# Allow visitors to update certain List programmatically in wss 3.0

Tags: sharepoint, wss-3.0

I need to allow visitors of the share point portal to update a list programmatically, but don't know how to do it.

Give a hint, please.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Well if you want a hint only, try googling:

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges
```

Maybe you should explain a bit more on your situation. Are your 'visitors' anonymous users? Are you creating a webpart or using out of box lists?

Answer (score 0):

You should consider breaking role inheritance on that list, then create a role assignment with role definition = (role definition = role including EditListItems permissions, principal = Visitors group).

(As a general rule, I don't recommend to depart much from the default security model neither to create granular permissions. It all becomes a management nightmare.)